# Order of Binomial addition

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

I was reading up a statement in probability which said that

$nC_0 + nC_1 + nC_2 +\dots+ nCm$ is of order $n^m$

where $nCm$ is notation for number of combinations from a collection of $n$ taking $m$ at a time

How to prove this mathematically? If not possible how to logically reason it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so close estimation. Must be better estimations of this sum, based on [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

For this question: just to write
$$
nC_0+nC_1+nC_2+\ldots+nC_m \\ = 1 + \dfrac{n}{1}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2} + \ldots + \dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{1\cdot 2 \cdots \cdot m}\\
\le 1+\frac{n}{1!}+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\ldots +\dfrac{n^m}{m!} \\
\le \left(1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{m!}\right)n^m \\
<e\cdot n^m,
$$

where $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)),  $e\approx2.71828$.